# Likelihood that two random sample sets come from the same population

Tags: sample, population

I have two random sample sets of 100 points, with 7 possible answers (A – G) each. The sets are as follows:

#### Set 1

```
A 49
B 22
C 14
D 7
E 4
F 4
G 0
```

#### Set 2

```
A 52
B 26
C 10
D 1
E 3
F 6
G 2
```

The values for A, B, and C seem close enough to each other to have come from the same population, but the values for D, E, F, and G seem quite different. However, the last four values in each set are much smaller than the first three, so maybe it's a statistical aberration?

What method can I use to work out how likely it is that these two sets come from the same population? I.e. I want a method that I can use without asking again.

Comment: Kolmogorov-Smirnov test might be one.

Comment: What do you know about the population? Do you know any properties of the answers A-G?

Comment: @Jan Given OP's last statement I figure he does not know / care.

Comment: @Jan The answers are all mutually exclusive and independent of each other. They could be the last flavour of ice cream people bought, as an example, assuming only one flavour can be bought at a time.

Comment: @user2974951 We would have to do some hypothesis testing in that case, but some assumption about the distribution or population would likely greatly enhance the result. In this case I would suggest hypothesis testing for a categorical distribution with the chi-squared test.

Comment: So you have two independent samples, both of size 100, where the answer for each individual can fall into one of seven different categories. Sounds to me like a typical Chi-squared test situation. However, make sure you check so that the Chi-square approximation is ok. There are different rules of thumb that can be applied.

Comment: Fisher's exact test is good, because frequencies in D E F G are so low, Pearson chi-square test maybe not applicable.